# Need help calling a function with parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a college project which is basically an elaborate news summarizer. I need to dynamically generate a list of article headings upon clicking a topic. 
I have been able to do that and assign the list Ids and Values dynamically using the for loop.
Each list is clickable and calls a parameterized function, with parameter as that lists value.
I am unsure how to define the function and syntax to make this a possibility.

I need to do this so that each heading when clicked can use AJAX to interact with a servlet and generate an article corresponding to the heading based on their values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        var i = 0;
        var set;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            var div = document.getElementById('content');
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<a href="#" onClick="rem()">'
                    + '<h2 id="theading'+i+'" value="'+i+'">HEADING ' + i
                    + ' WILL GO HERE</h2></a><br>';
        }
    }

    function rem(value) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = value
                + '<h1>THE NEWS WILL GO HERE</h1>';
    }
</script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
    color: orange;
}
</style>

<body>
    <a href="#" onClick="change()"><h3>TOPIC</h3></a>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I write the code so that rem() function can be called with its parameter as the value of its corresponding list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would completely rewrite your first function:

```
function change() {
    var i = 0;
    var set;
    var div = document.getElementById('content');
    div.innerHTML = '';
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = "#";
        a.onclick = rem.bind(null, i); // Here is the magical part
        a.innerHTML = '<h2 id="theading'+i+'">HEADING ' + i
                + ' WILL GO HERE</h2>';

        div.appendChild(a);
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow!! It worked like magic indeed. Thanks a ton. The code is neat and efficient. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that value to method `rem()`.

I am not absolute sure which value you wan't to pass for it but changing:

```
onclick="rem()"
```

to:

```
onclick="rem(' + i + ')"
```

will call method rem with an value of `i` when the link is clicked.

After that you can and should discard `value="'+i+'` from your `h2` tag. It is not valid HTML.

Cheers.

Comment: @AnjulGarg Great to hear that :), also welcome to stackoverflow. I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/tour first and after that accepting one of the answers as a solution (if your problem is solved, if not, ask more information in the comments or modify your question). People including you get reputation points for doing that. Hence, reputation system is one of the core reasons why ppl are so active here in the first place. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Embrace the power of `this`.

```
onClick="rem(this)"
```

*This* will pass a reference to the clicked element. From there you can then traverse the DOM, using parents and children, to locate other elements, without having to deal with messy IDs.

Comment: It is passing the browser address as reference. i.e,

http://localhost:8888/#
THE NEWS WILL GO HERE

However, I need to pass something unique which will help me call a different function for each heading.

Comment: You might want to try a templating library. It allows you to create HTML templates with embedded variables instead of building things up from strings in JS. Take a look at underscore.js, but there are many others.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I am still in the very early stages of js so trying to keep things simple.